# CLT in Diebold & Mariano (1995)

Tags: time-series, mathematical-statistics, central-limit-theorem, diebold-mariano-test

The Diebold-Mariano (DM) statistic is derived as follows:

Assuming the loss-differential between the two models  $d_t$ is covariance stationary:

$$\begin{cases}
    \mathbb{E}[d_t] = \mu> 0 & \forall t  \\
    \text{Cov}(d_{s}, d_{t}) = \gamma(t-s)& \forall t  \\
    0 < \text{Var}(d_{t}) = \sigma^2 < \infty & \forall t 
  \end{cases}$$

$\Rightarrow \sqrt{T}(\overline{d} - \mu) \overset{d}{\rightarrow} N(0, 2\pi f_d(0))$

where $\overline{d}$ is the sample mean of the $d_t$ and $f_d(0)$ is the spectral density of d evaluated at zero.

Hence for an appropriate estimate of $f_d(0)$,

$$DM = \frac{\overline{d}}{\sqrt{\frac{{2\pi}\widehat{f_d(0)}}{T}}} \overset{a}{\sim} N(0,1) \hspace{.2cm}\text{if} \hspace{.2cm}\mu = 0.$$

I'd like to know which CLT gives the convergence in distribution and how to show it.

**EDIT** the answer is emabrassingly simple. You can find it

[here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4154543/asymptotic-distribution-of-the-sample-average-of-covariance-stationary-time-seri)

Comment: If you found an answer to your question, you should post an answer, rather than answer in the question

Comment: @Glen_b I asked the same question at math.stackexchange.com and got a response. Why can't I just link it

Comment: I had not realized you had asked the same question on more than one site. Please see the third-last paragraph here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Dear @Glen_b I know that cross-posting is discouraged therefore I waited for 25 days before I did that.